# Is there a script to re-import exported DISQUS comments?

Tags: disqus

I've implemented DISQUS on one of my main sites. However, I have 22 pages that I want to move over to a new domain/forum. Those 22 pages have 177 comments in DISQUS, which I'd rather not lose.

I would assume that I'm not the only one who wishes to move comments from one site to another, but at this time it appears DISQUS still doesn't support this functionality.

Before I write the script to parse the exported XML and create the XML format DISQUS requires, is there already a script that will do this for me? Searches return absolutely nothing relevant on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've never seen any scripts to do that kind of re-formatting.

To elaborate on the root topic here, our export format is not designed for re-import; it's designed for backup and storage purposes. So it doesn't follow the same schema as our custom XML import format (which is based on the WXR schema for the most part).

We offer URL migration tools which allow you to re-associate your comment threads with new URLs. More info on those at http://docs.disqus.com/help/39/. Those should make the forum move unnecessary.

If those aren't the tools you're looking for, or those won't fully do the job for you, would you kindly elaborate as to what exactly you're looking to do and why? (For example, why the comments need to be moved to an entirely new Disqus forum.)

Comment: So I have a base forum that I used for my blog. At this point I'm looking at re-doing my blog completely, and two fairly large components make sense to be moved to their own/different domains. While I could keep the forum name of the old site, I'd prefer to branch them off, since it just makes sense. I've used the migration utility to at least get those moved to a different domain working again. While it's not technically necessary, I just think of forums as belonging to a particular domain.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Sure that makes sense and is actually how Disqus is most often used. It's what we recommend, even :) Except typically we recommend doing that up-front since the system itself wasn't designed to split forums after they're created; things can break when that happens. It'd certainly be possible to write a script that converts the export format to our import format (this is also something we're considering); at that point you'd just need to make sure to delete the extraneous comments from the original forum, so they don't show up twice in people's profiles.